# Ignore alphabets in a cell, only numbers should be checked

Tags: vba, excel

```
 Sub highlight(phm as variant)
 Dim w As Workbook
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim rn As Range
 Dim k As Long
 Dim number() As integer

 If phm <> 0 Then

 phm = Split(phm, ",")
 ReDim number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer

 Set sh = w.Worksheets("sheet1")
sh.Select
Cells.Find("Number Type").Select

Set rn = sh6.UsedRange
k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To k
For j = LBound(number) To UBound(number)
number(j) = CInt(phm(j))
If Err.number = 0 Then
If ActiveCell.Value = number(j) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Else
Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Exit For
End If
End If

Next j
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
Next i


End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save


End Sub
```

I want to modify the above code in such a way that alphabets are ignored if present in any cell.

For example, a cell may contain "hello 9811",then it should not be highlighted.Checking should be done only on numbers in the cell

phm contains data like this: "9811,7849" etc..

Comment: Can you edit your example to make it more clear

Comment: Duplicate of [ignore alphabets while looping through cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548004/ignore-alphabets-while-looping-through-cells).

Comment: Do check this site under the tags before you post a question. Watch out:  you have two accounts it seems - you may get a warning or one account will be removed by the site moderators.

Comment: @JasmitaSagi if you have two accounts i will advise you visit the following [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your program. The program tries to convert the cell's value to an integer. Only if it succeeds in doing so, then `Activecell.Value` is compared to `number(j)`.

```
Sub Highlight()

    ...same code as yours...

    Cells.Find("hello").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1

    ' ignore errors related to CInt conversion that will follow
    On Error Resume Next

    For x = 1 To k
      For j = 0 To UBound(number)

        ' try to convert value to integer
        TempNumber = CInt(ActiveCell.Value)

        ' if value was an integer, work on it
        If Err.number = 0 Then
            If ActiveCell.Value <> number(j) Then
               Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
               Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
               Exit For
            End If
        End If

      Next j

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.

    Next x

End Sub
```

**EDIT based on change in requirement**

```
Sub Test()
    highlight ("9811,7849")
End Sub

Sub highlight(phm As Variant)

    Dim w As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rn As Range
    Dim k As Long
    Dim number() As Integer

    ' newly added variables
    Dim TempNumber As Integer
    Dim phmInt As Variant
    Dim phmFound As Boolean

    If phm <> 0 Then

        ' split the numbers
        phm = Split(phm, ",")
        ReDim number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer

        Set sh = Worksheets("sheet1")
        sh.Select
        Cells.Find("Number Type").Select

        Set rn = sh.UsedRange
        k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1

        For i = 1 To k

            On Error Resume Next

            ' try to check if active cell is an integer
            ' and proceed only if it is an integer
            TempNumber = CInt(ActiveCell.Value)
            If Err.number = 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0

                ' set phmFound to false and then see if
                ' active cell's value matches any item in phm array
                phmFound = False
                For Each phmInt In phm
                    If CInt(ActiveCell.Value) = CInt(phmInt) Then
                        phmFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next phmInt

                ' if active cell's value matched at least one item
                ' in phm array, don't colorize it. Otherwise colorize it
                ActiveCell.Select
                If phmFound Then
                    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Else
                    Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If

            End If
            Err.Clear

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Requirement: 9811 and 7848 are entered so any cell in this format- hello 9811,9811,7848,abc 7848 should NOT be highlighted...remaining cells with any other content other than the above mentioned should be highlighted

Sub Test()
    highlight ("9811,7848")
End Sub

```
Sub highlight(phm As Variant)

    Dim w As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rn As Range
    Dim k As Long
    Dim number() As Integer

    ' newly added variables
    Dim TempNumber As Integer
    Dim phmInt As Variant
    Dim phmFound As Boolean

    If phm <> 0 Then

        ' split the numbers
        phm = Split(phm, ",")
        ReDim number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer

        Set sh = Worksheets("sheet1")
        sh.Select
        Cells.Find("Number Type").Select

        Set rn = sh.UsedRange
        k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1

        For i = 1 To k

            ' does the cell have the number we are looking for?
            phmFound = False
            For Each phmInt In phm
                TempNumber = InStr(Trim(ActiveCell.Text), CStr(phmInt))
                If TempNumber > 0 Then
                    ' check if there is any number after phmint
                    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(Trim(ActiveCell.Text), TempNumber + Len(CStr(phmInt)), 1)) Then
                        phmFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next phmInt

            ' if active cell's value matched at least one item
            ' in phm array, don't colorize it. Otherwise colorize it
            ActiveCell.Select
            If phmFound Then
                Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Else
                Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added code in response to the edited question

Comment: @zedfoxus-TempNumber = CInt(ActiveCell.Value) this line gives me type mismatch error

Comment: I've made appropriate change in the 2nd block of code under Edit based on change in requirement. Try that out

Comment: @zedfoxus-It works partially good. Its is not highlighting- 9811,7849,abc 9811,abc 7849.This is correct. But it is not  highlighting -abc 3846 but just highlighting 3846.

Comment: What numbers are in your array?

Comment: @zedfoxus-they are dynamic..they will be entered from my GUI, eg. 9811 and 7848 are entered so any cell in this format- hello 9811,9811,7848,abc 7848 should NOT be highlighted...remaining cells with any other content other than the above mentioned  should be highlighted

Comment: Oh, that should be simple. I'll update the code in an hour or so

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Function to your code

example

```
Public Function OnlyDigits(pInput As String) As String
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\D"
        OnlyDigits = .replace(pInput, vbNullString)
    End With
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

here is the complete code.

```
Sub highlight(phm As Variant)
    Dim w           As Workbook
    Dim sh          As Worksheet
    Dim x           As Integer
    Dim rn          As Range
    Dim k           As Long
    Dim Number()    As Integer

    If phm <> 0 Then
    phm = Split(phm, ",")
    ReDim Number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer

    Set sh = w.Worksheets("sheet1")
    sh.Select
    Cells.Find("Number Type").Select

    Set rn = sh6.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.count + rn.Row - 1
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To k
        For j = LBound(Number) To UBound(Number)
            Number(j) = CInt(phm(j))
                If Err.Number = 0 Then
                    If Val(OnlyDigits(ActiveCell.Value)) = Number(j) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Else
                        Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
        Next i
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Public Function OnlyDigits(pInput As String) As String
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\D"
        OnlyDigits = .replace(pInput, vbNullString)
    End With
    Set objRegExp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: If Val(OnlyDigits(ActiveCell.Value)) = Number(j) Or IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
                        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                    Else
                        Selection.Interior.Color = vbGreen

Comment: All the cells except blank cells are highlighted

Comment: i dont want blank cells to be highlighted